# Add static segment to route to make pagination more friendly asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my website I made my urls in general more friendly by using slugs. I would like to make the url information related to paging more friendly too by changing

```
 www.example.com/controller/action/1  // 1 represents the page
```

to

```
 www.example.com/controller/action/page-1
```

I don't care if it isn't possible but it would be desirable.

I've tried to decorate my action with

```
[Route("action/page-{pagina?}")]
public IActionResult Action(int page= 1)
```

when navigating a get this.

the optional parameter 'page' is preceded by an invalid segment 'page-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using an optional parameter with a constraint and then parse the parameter to get the page number

```
//Matches action
//Matches action/page-1
[Route("action/{page:regex(^page-\d$)?}")]
public IActionResult Action(string page = "page-1") {
    //... parse page
    // page number = page.Replace("page-", "");
    // then int.Parse() page number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully done this in my `Startup.cs` in the Configure method

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {

  /* code removed for brevity */

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteName",
    template: "action/page-{pageNumber}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "YourController", Action = "Action" }
  );

});
```

Your controller would then be...

```
public IActionResult Action(int page= 1)
```

It depends on if you need to use attribute routing or not.